# Can I choose lines from my CSV for Dygraphs to pull from?

Tags: dygraphs

I'm making a website which will have 6 or 8 charts on different pages, ideally they'll all use the same CSV.

I need to pull different parts of the CSV to create different charts.

Is this possible, or do we need separate CSV files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [visibility option](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#visibility) to only chart a subset of the series in your CSV file. Note that this might issue the same XHR for your CSV file more than once. Using separate CSVs or processing the CSV file in the client will be more efficient.